# Stored procedure not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have trouble converting this to stored procedure

//The string included in the sql statement:

```
        string employer = Session["Employer"].ToString();
```

then the sql statement

update tblWorkData set EmployerName='"+txtemployername.text+"' where EmployerName='"+Employer+"' //the string above

This works fine in asp.net
But when I turn it into stored procedure,

```
    create proc updateWork

    @EmployerName nvarchar(max)

    as

    begin

    update tblWorkData set EmployerName=@EmployerName where EmployerName=@EmployerName
    end
```

Now when I execute the sp on asp.net,

```
    string update = "updateWork '"+employer+"','"+txtemployername.text+"'";
```

I got an error saying "too many arguements". What should I do?

Comment: The `update tblWorkData set EmployerName=@EmployerName where EmployerName=@EmployerName` has no meaning and do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure only takes one argument and you're calling it with two. To fix this you need to alter the procedure to take two arguments like this:

```
create proc updateWork
  @EmployerName nvarchar(max),
  @Employer nvarchar(max)

as

  begin

  update tblWorkData set EmployerName=@EmployerName where EmployerName=@Employer

  end
```

I changed the `where`clause as I guess you meant it to be. As it was before it didn't actually do anything at all.

On a side note you might want to look into how to properly call procedures and how to add parameters in a way that isn't vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to the database in order to execute sql statements:

```
     string employer = Session["Employer"].ToString();

     // assume connectionString is a valid connection string

     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
         connection.Open();
         SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = "updatework";
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployerName", employer);
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```